# Limiting workload to control memory useage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a web application. On each request, it loads a whole file into memory and does something asynchronous with its contents.

To avoid running out of memory, I'd like to limit the number of files I can process concurrently. If the size of the file was constant and known up-front, [async.queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) would be perfect. But I don't know the file sizes. So, stated more accurately, I really want to limit the amount of memory I'm currently occupying, rather than specifying a fixed limit on the number of files.

My question is whether there is a library out there that would let me do something like this:

```
// Use the fictitious Limiter
var limiter = new Limiter(worker, 10 * 1024 * 1024); // limit to 10 MB

// process foo.txt, which we know is 6MB
limiter.push("foo.txt", 6 * 1024 * 1024);
// ask to process bar.txt, but it will be delayed until foo is complete
// because 6 + 6 > 10
limiter.push("bar.txt", 6 * 1024 * 1024);

// The worker is the same as the one used by async.queue
function worker(task, callback){
    var filename = task;
    //load whole file and do asynchronous stuff with it
    doSomething(filename, function(){
        // we're done with the file
        callback();
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry... Off topic because: "Request for software library".

Comment: no, but it's easy enough to build your own, looks like you have half the code in your example...

Comment: You're really looking at a modified semaphore... pick an existing semaphore implementation and adapt it to your needs (Don't forget to contribute back!)

Comment: Thanks, @Amit. Coming from the Java world, I was still thinking of a semaphore as a multi-threading thing. But, of course, the same construct can be used in Node. I found a library and was actually able to use it as-is. Code included in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing more than a semaphore is needed for this. See https://github.com/abrkn/semaphore.js

The code for dealing with files in memory would then follow this pattern:

```
var sem = require('semaphore')(10 * 1024 * 1024);

var size = 6 * 1024 * 1024;
processFile("foo.txt", size);
processFile("bar.txt", size);


function processFile(filename, size){
     sem.take(size, function(){
        console.log(filename);
        // Pretend it takes 1 second to deal with file
        setTimeout(function(){
            sem.leave(size);
        }, 1000);
     });
}
```